# Decoding an unconventional coordinate system

Tags: esri-geodatabase, utm, transit

I've been trying to collect bus location data. However, the GPS coordinates the website gives me are very strange. For example,

> 'Lat': 3582409.5140834446,
>
> 'Long': -10725363.693190178,

... corresponds to somewhere in Texas A&M University, College Station, TX, USA.

I'm quite a stranger to GIS, so I don't know what this means. I thought this was UTM, but conversion using 14R grid results in conventional coordinates of somewhere across the world.

The website I am retrieving data from has "wkid: 4326" in the source code and uses esri, but that doesn't help me make sense of anything.

Comment: Looks like you have WGS84 coordinates in minutes-degrees-seconds (and not in decimal degrees). What's the website and expected location (if not College Station, TX)?

Comment: College Station is in the vicinity of 30.6280° N, 96.3344° W, so it's not right for DDMMSS.SSS

Comment: Looks to me like those coordinates are EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t6rj9g5u/1/)